# How to observe a change in viewModel in order to reload collectionView using RxSwift?

Tags: swift, mvvm, uicollectionview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have the following code to configure my collectionView:

```
viewModel?
    .observableExercises
    .bindTo(
        exercisesCollectionView
            .rx
            .items(cellIdentifier: "My identifier",
                   cellType: ExerciseCollectionViewCell.self)) {
                    index, exercise, cell in
                    cell.exercise = exercise
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

It all works fine at first, but later when my `viewModel.observableExercises` gets updated I would like to have the `exercisesCollectionView` reload its data. How should I do it?

Comment: It should reload by it self

Comment: Maybe the problem is how I create the `observableExercises`. As for now I have an array of exercises and I create the observable with the `just` operator. The problem is that it emits the array and then `complete`. Is there a better way to create the observable?

Comment: Don't emit the complete. That is why it is not reloading

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! I changed the implementation of my viewModel to have a Variable<[String]> instead of an Observable<[String]>. So whenever I change the `observableExercises.value` the collectionView reloads perfectly.